# How to create a dynamic GraphQL query using variables in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, graphql

I have a graphQL query that looks like this:

```
$query = <<<'JSON'
query{
   mainProducts(where:{productType:{eq:2}}) {
       name, productID
   }
}
JSON;
$variables = '';

$json = json_encode(['query' => $query, 'variables' => $variables]);

$chObj = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chObj, CURLOPT_URL, ‘https://whateverurlitis.com’);
curl_setopt($chObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($chObj, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($chObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($chObj, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($chObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($chObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
     array(
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: bearer '.MYTOKEN 
        )
    ); 

$response = curl_exec($chObj);
echo $response;
```

My issue is, at the moment I need to replace the query parameter with a variable to make it dynamic, and the variable can be either a number or array of numbers and I would need to loop them.

Could someone please enlighten me on how to replace the number 2 for `productType` with a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no need to differentiate between `either a number or array of numbers`. If it's just one number, you could just pass an array with one number. This will make your schema simpler.

In order to add dynamic variables to the query, you'll need to redo your query to allow passing variables. The following should do the trick:

```
query MainProducts($productTypes: [Int!]!) {
   mainProducts(where:{productType:{eq:$productTypes}}) {
       name, productID
   }
}
```

This way, you'll be able to pass `productTypes` variable of type `[Int!]!`, which is an array of integers.

Now, all that's left is to pass product types IDs to the query as a variable:

```
$variables = [1,2,3];
```

You can read more about passing arguments to a query [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
whereabouts should I place the $variables = [1,2,3];
just after the  query's  closing curly brackets ( } ) ?
and do I rename it as productTypes or keep is as variable? It seems like the doc you sent me is more of nodeJS rather than PHP

Comment: The body of your request should remain `json_encode(['query' => $query, 'variables' => $variables]);`